# Do "the alpha and the omega" and "from A to Z" have the same meaning or something in common?

Tags: idioms

The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition, as one can read it on The Free Dictionary, says:

> **alpha and omega**, noun:
>   1. The first and the last: "I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending, saith the Lord" (Revelation 1:8).
>   2. The most important part.

It is a noun that resembles to the Italian, literally, "from A to Z", an expression used to say that a certain thing is complete. "The report is complete from A to Z"  means that it doesn't lack anything, and probably it is the same in English.

After reading the above definition, in the light of what I said, I began wondering if the two expressions, "tha alpha and the omega" and "from A to Z", mean the same thing.

1) "I was forced to read the alpha and omega of 'The Principia Mathematica', written by Alfred North Whitehead"

2) "I was forced to read, from A to Z,  'The Principia Mathematica', written by Alfred North Whitehead"

Can anybody explain the difference in meaning between 1) and 2)?

Comment: *Alpha and omega* is not at all the same thing as *from A to Z*.

Comment: @tchrist, so one cannot say, for instance, "She was forced to read the alpha and omega of that book" as an alternative version of "She was forced to read that book from A to Z"?

Comment: That’s right: you cannot say that.

Comment: @tchrist, ah, and what is the difference in meaning?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Good question for you!

Comment: I believe an English expression that means the same as Alpha/Omega is, "Terri is the ***end-all and be-all*** of that team."

Comment: From here: http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Apocalisse%201&version=CEI - there are five Italian-language versions of the bible available; four out of five have that passage as something like: *Io sono l'Alfa e l'Omega* - this appears to be the exact equivalent of the English phrase in the question.

Comment: @Mark, I assure you that there are no more than ten Italians that know and use "Io sono l'Alfa e l'Omega", and if one of them tells me that I start to laugh out loud!

Comment: @tchrist, where are you? I'm waiting to know the difference in meaning between "She was forced to read the alpha and omega of that book" and "She was forced to read that book from A to Z"?

Comment: @Carlo_R. *Alpha and omega* has eschatological connotations that *A to Z* lacks.

Comment: @Carlo_R., the difference between those two sentences is that “She was forced to read the alpha and omega of that book” doesn’t make very much sense. It could perhaps be taken to mean “She was forced to read the most important parts of that book”, but it sounds very odd. If you say that _X_ is the alpha and omega of _Y_, it means _X_ is the one thing that is absolutely crucial to _Y_. Without _X_, _Y_ cannot be/function, or is useless. Kristina’s example is good: “Terri is the alpha and omega of the team—without her, they would lose all their matches”.

Comment: @Janus, actually very instructive; but how much is that idiom used in day-by-day speech? In my country there is almost no one that use it, even if the Bible is a well known book here around (Italy)?

Comment: It is very well-_known_ and everyone will recognise it; but I wouldn’t say it’s a turn of phrase people use very much in their everyday lives. ‘Be-all and end-all’ is more common (or at least that is my immediate impression—I haven’t researched it at all).

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: That *end all and be all* is definitely a somewhat non-standard American variant. We English *people* (read, *Brits*) overwhelmingly classify ourselves as the [*be all and end all*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=end+all+and+be+all%2Cbe+all+and+end+all&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) in such matters.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, oops. you're right, I got it backwards.  It's be all and end all.

Comment: @Kristina: If we buy into that NGram link, the expression is 2-3 times more common overall in the UK than the US, but briefly (around 1917) the "face-about-arse" version was actually *more* common in the US. Maybe US soldiers picked it up in WW1, but garbled it a bit on the way home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your edited question is that neither version is normal, because your assumption that 'probably it is the same in English' is unfounded.

*Alpha and omega*, derived from the Biblical reference, can indeed mean 'the important part': "Set theory is the alpha and omega of the symbolic logic in Whitehead's *Principia Mathematica*'.  'From A to Z' means 'all of it'; "I know Whitehead's symbolic logic from A to Z". But if, as in your example, you mean 'starting at the first page and finishing at the last', the phrase is "I read Whitehead's *Principia Mathematica* from beginning to end".

Incidentally, the book is not "The Principia Mathematica", it is "Russell and Whitehead's *Principia Mathematica*."  There is no article: since the words are in Latin they are italicised; and the authors must be named, to distinguish their book from Newton's predecessor with the same title.

Comment: Tim, what a erudite answer! +1, surely.

Comment: Tim, or should it be "what erudite an answer" :)

Comment: @Carlo_R.: actually either 'What an erudite answer' or 'How erudite an answer' (and whether it's true or not doesn't change the grammar).

Answer (score 3):

They more or less mean the same thing they just have a different "ring" to it.  In the Bible, God was referring to something slightly different.

In the Greek alphabet "alpha" is the first letter and "omega" is the last.  In this case, he's saying he's the beginning, the end and everything in-between.

Comment: They may mean the same thing only in terms of representing the first and last letter of the two alphabets, but the *expressions* are not interchangeable in their use.

Comment: @Kirstina Lopez: Someone edited my answer...

Comment: I reviewed the edit and think they went too far - and totally changed the meaning.  You can roll it back and tweak it again if you want.  Your original answer was more accurate in my mind. :-)

Comment: @Kristina Lopex: I thought so too, but didn't know I could roll it back.  It was the first time I've ever had a major edit on any of these sites.  Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @TimLymington: Apparently I just need to quit messing with things.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[In context](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%201:7-9&version=WE), `Alpha and Omega` doesn't mean "the important parts". It's not talking about alphabet, either. [It's talking about the beginning, [middle] and the end](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Revelation%201:8). The idea is that the speaker has always been around from the beginning of time to the end of time.

> <sup>8</sup> The Lord God says, `I am the First and the Last. I am the beginning and the ending. I live now. I always have lived, and I will come again.
>   (Worldwide English)

The emphasis is more on the level of *always* rather than range.

Something nearly equivalent:

> When I started reading, I was reading before anyone, I'm still reading, and will read when people stop reading.

It's the difference between *I've done everything X* and *I've never stopped doing X*.

Certainly, [there is more to it](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/who-is-speaking-in-revelation-18) than just this post, and [hermeneutics.se] might be just the place to gather more insight.

Comment: In a Christian context, certainly. But in a normal English context, the meaning has expanded to 'the most important part', as the dictionary definition says.

Comment: @TimLymington Of course, context will define the meaning. I doubt "the important parts" was intended in the source text.